# Kubernetes Kops - set sysctl flag on kubelet

Tags: kubernetes, kops, sysctl

We need to enable some sysctl parameters in kubernetes. This should be achievable with the below annotation in the Deployment.

```
annotations:
  security.alpha.kubernetes.io/unsafe-sysctls: net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="10240 65535"
```

When doing so the container fails to start with the error:

```
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  8s (x12 over 19s)  kubelet, <node>  Failed create pod sandbox.
```

The solution looks to be to add this flag to the kublet:

```
--experimental-allowed-unsafe-sysctls
```

Which for other flags can be done under *kubelet* in

```
kops edit cluster
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this as it refuses to pick up the setting when entering the flag there.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2020-05-18, the proper config is, for example:

```
  kubelet:                                                                                                                             
    allowedUnsafeSysctls:                                                                                                              
    - net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="10240 65535"
```

In general, all KOPS config must be camelCased.

From [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/f5093e4148f18acaea2625d4d7b13037f4176f38/pkg/apis/kops/v1alpha2/componentconfig.go#L178), KOPS 1.16.2+

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this was merged back in May, you can see the PR here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/pull/5104/files

You'd enable it with:

```
spec:
  kubelet:
    ExperimentalAllowedUnsafeSysctls:
      - 'net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="10240 65535"'
```

It seems the flag takes a stringSlice, so you'd need to pass an array.

If that doesn't work, ensure you're using the right version of kops

Comment: Kops responds with *Found fields that are not recognized* for ExperimentalAllowedUnsafeSysctls. I have tried with kops versions 1.9.2 and 1.10. Running kubernetes 1.9.6.